# Symfony3 FossUserBundle render registration form from another controller in order to register via ajax

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

On my Symfony 3 project I use FossUserBundle and what I want to acheive is to render the extended form I developed for Registration page to another controller *WITHOUT* redirect.

In other words what I want to achieve is to make `/register`  routes to be called via Ajax and on `/` to render the form. Therefore I want to do the first step and try to render the form in `/` instead of `/register` but all the post actions will be done in `/register`

Therefore I tried the following:

I have changed the `Appbundle` class as:

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

And tried on `AppBundle\Controller\Pages` class the following:

1.To render the form without extending the  `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController`;

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;


/**
 * @author pcmagas
 * Class that loads miscellanous pages
 */
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *@Route("/", name="index")
     *@Method("GET")
     */
    function homePage()
    {
        $form = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form');

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                     'form' => $form->createView(),
             ));
    }
}
```

2.To extend the `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController` and try to render the form:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

/**
 * @author pcmagas
 * Class that loads miscellanous pages
 */
class PagesController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     *@Route("/", name="index")
     *@Method("GET")
     */
    function homePage()
    {
        $form = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form');

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                     'form' => $form->createView(),
             ));
    }
}
```

Both of these methods fail to render the form (just render it remember the `/register` route will handle the form when submited via ajax.) and return the following error message:

> You have requested a non-existent service "fos_user.registration.form". Did you mean one of these: "fos_user.registration.form.factory", "fos_user.registration.form.type"?

Do you have any sort of Idea how to do that?

## Edit 1

I tried:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

/**
 * @author pcmagas
 * Class that loads miscellanous pages
 */
class PagesController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     *@Route("/", name="index")
     *@Method("GET")
     */
    function homePage()
    {
        $form = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.type');

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                     'form' => $form->createView(),
             ));
    }
}
```

With error:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createView" of class "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType".

Also similar result with:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "createView" of class "FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FormFactory".

Comment: try to change fos_user.registration.form to fos_user.registration.form.type in your PagesController

Comment: I used the `fos_user.registration.form.factory"` without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this is what worked for me:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @author pcmagas
 * Class that loads miscellanous pages
 */
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *@Route("/", name="index")
     *@Method("GET")
     */
    function homePage()
    {
        $form = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        $form = $form->createForm();

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.twig', array(
                     'form' => $form->createView(),
             ));
    }
}
```